# How to embed a base64 image into HTML email via Python 3.5?

Tags: python, html-email, mime

I am tying to build an email that will embed an image base64 so that way it displays properly when my coworkers open it. I'm not really sure how to get there from a file and what I have now.

This runs great, but I've not been able to successfully embed an image.  I need to imbed image1.jpg.

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage


# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "me@.com"
you = "you@.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Sent using Python :) "
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you



# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "This is an HTML body. I would like to embed a base64 image."
html = """\
<html>
    <body>
        <p>This is an HTML body.<br>
           I would like to embed a base64 image.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')


# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 5):

I tested it only with base64 image embeded in HTML file but it should be the same.

---

You have to read image as bytes, encode to base64, convert it to string and then use in

```
  '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data_base64 + '">'
```

Working example to embed base64 image in HTML file:

```
import base64

data = open('image.jpg', 'rb').read() # read bytes from file
data_base64 = base64.b64encode(data)  # encode to base64 (bytes)
data_base64 = data_base64.decode()    # convert bytes to string

print(data_base64)

#html = '<html><body><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data_base64 + '"></body></html>' # embed in html
html = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data_base64 + '">' # embed in html
open('output.html', 'w').write(html)
```

---

Example [encode and decode base64 image](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/decode-encode/base64-tiff-png-jpg-html/main-jpg.py)